# How to convert matrix to RDD[Vector] in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to convert from `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix` to `RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]` in Spark?

The matrix is generated from SVD, and I am using the results from SVD to do clustering analysis.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the types? (Is `Vector` the immutable Scala Vector (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector) or Java's `java.util.Vector`, or something from Python? How the matrix is represented, what is its type?)

Comment: @GáborBakos: From Jiang's edit it appears we're talking about MLlib's `Matrix` and `Vector`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MLlib's `Matrix` is a small local matrix. It would probably be more efficient to analyze it locally instead of turning it into an RDD.

Anyway, if your clustering only supports RDD as its input, here's how you can do the transformation:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._
def toRDD(m: Matrix): RDD[Vector] = {
  val columns = m.toArray.grouped(m.numRows)
  val rows = columns.toSeq.transpose // Skip this if you want a column-major RDD.
  val vectors = rows.map(row => new DenseVector(row.toArray))
  sc.parallelize(vectors)
}
```

Comment: The matrix is generated from the svd method. I want to use the kmeans cluster method to  find clusters of the matrix, but the kmeans method only accepts RDD.

Comment: Ah, I see! I've updated the answer to be less snarky :). Hope the code works anyway!

Comment: Thank you very much! I am from the field of machine learning, and I am very new to Spark and Scala. From the perspective of machine learning, as long as they are the same data, I do not care about how they are stored or represented in memory. So I am having a very hard time converting the same data from one format to another. Do you have any thoughts about my experience? Thanks again.

Comment: I think this disconnect between local structures and distributed structures sucks. I only use MLlib a very little, so I cannot say if this could be fixed. Perhaps you could ask on the users' mailing list (see http://spark.apache.org/community.html) or wait some more and hope someone more knowledgeable than me sees this question.

Comment: How to apply this convert for pca.@DanielDarabos

Comment: No idea, sorry. If it's not clear from the docs (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-dimensionality-reduction#principal-component-analysis-pca) maybe it's worth asking a new question!