# Convert RDD of Matrix to RDD of Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a RDD[Matrix[Double]] and want to convert it to RDD[Vector] (Each row in the Matrix will be converted to a Vector).

I've seen related answer like [Convert Matrix to RowMatrix in Apache Spark using Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169841/convert-matrix-to-rowmatrix-in-apache-spark-using-scala/30170898#30170898), but it's one Matrix to RDD of Vector. While my case is RDD of Matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flatMap on [code to convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28172826/1206998) `Matrix` to `Seq[Vector]`:

```
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28172826/1206998
def toSeqOfVector(m: Matrix): Seq[Vector] = {
  val columns = m.toArray.grouped(m.numRows)
  val rows = columns.toSeq.transpose // Skip this if you want a column-major RDD.
  rows.map(row => new DenseVector(row.toArray))
}

val matrices: RDD[Matrix] = ??? // your input
val vectors:  RDD[Vector] = matrices.flatMap(toSeqOfVector)
```

Note: I didn't test this code, but this is the principle